# Running multiple transforms on gulp/browserify bundle

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, browserify

I have a React component that I've been exporting to a bundle file. I've been successfully transforming it using babelify, however, I now would like to run envify on it. I can't seem to figure out how to run multiple transforms using browserify. I think it must be possible, but I can't tell if my syntax is slightly off or if I need to write a custom transform or if I should specify the transforms in my package.json. Here is the code in my gulp file:

```
 var bundleComponent = function(bundler, source, component) {
   //bundler is just browserify('./client/components/TVScheduleTab/render.js')

   gutil.log('Bundling ' + component)

  return bundler
  //this throws an error
    .transform(babelify, envify({
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }))
    .bundle()
    .on('error', function(e){
      gutil.log(e);
    })
    .pipe(source)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('output/'));
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried chaining? **Correct solution is in comments**

```
 var bundleComponent = function(bundler, source, component) {
   //bundler is just browserify('./client/components/TVScheduleTab/render.js')

   gutil.log('Bundling ' + component)

  return bundler
  //this throws an error
    .transform(babelify)
    .transform(envify({
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }))
    .bundle()
    .on('error', function(e){
      gutil.log(e);
    })
    .pipe(source)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('output/'));
};
```

Comment: Yes, and I've also tried adding passing them in as an array and also specifying them in an object I pass into browserify. I also have `"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },` in my package.json. Not sure if that is interfering in any way.

Comment: Also this seems to be important, but it is not obvious how you are requiring envify - https://github.com/hughsk/envify/issues/7#issuecomment-45418761

Comment: Thanks! It worked when I used `browserify({
     'entries': ['./client/components/TVScheduleTab/render.js'],
     'transform': [[babelify], ['envify', {'global': true, NODE_ENV: 'production'}]] 
    }`

Comment: it should be noted that `envify` should be imported through `require('envify/custom')`

Answer (score 2):

Although this answer appears after the accepted answer, and the accepted somewhat covers the question, I wanted to make it clear without the need to navigate through the linked github issue.

Chaining, in particular with `envify`, should look like:

```
// NOTE: the "custom" part
var envify = require('envify/custom');

gulp.task('build-production', function() {
    browserify(browserifyOptions)
        .transform(babelify.configure(babelifyOptions))
        .transform(envify({
            NODE_ENV: 'production'
        }))
        .bundle()
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/production/js'));
});
```